How can gelling agents "dissolve" in the liquid phase as a "colloid" mixture?
Gelling agents according to Wikipedia:

Some thickening agents are gelling agents (gellants), forming a gel, dissolving in the liquid phase as a colloid mixture...

But colloid according to Wikipedia:

A colloid is a mixture in which one substance consisting of
microscopically dispersed insoluble particles is suspended throughout
another substance.

Gelling agents dissolving as a colloid seem contradictory to me. Because colloid is insoluable. Am I missing something?


Gelling agents dissolving as a colloid seem contradictory to me.
Because colloid is insoluble. Am I missing something?

Do not take Wikipedia too literally. This is why we still have libraries. The correct term, instead of dissolving should be dispersed. Colloids are dispersions. A gel is a dispersion of a solid in a liquid.
Now there is a thin line between being dispersed and dissolved. It is just the matter of size.
OP further asks: Then, is it incorrect to describe gelling agents like pectin and inulin as 'soluble' dietary fibers?

Soluble dietary fiber (SDF) SDF is hydrophilic, non-crystalline, and
easily wetted by the aqueous gastrointestinal fluid, forming viscous
colloidal dispersions or gels when hydrated.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/food-science/soluble-dietary-fiber
Yes, the the usage of soluble is perhaps a misnomer here. As I stated above, there is a thin line between soluble and being dispersed.  Look up the properties of colloids from a good physical chemistry textbook.

Thank you for answer. Then, is it incorrect to describe gelling agents like pectin and inulin as 'soluble' dietary fibers?

Wikipedia is wrong when stating that "gelling agents, dissolving in the liquid phase as a colloid mixture". A colloid mixture is not a solution. If something is dissolved in water, it forms a solution, it does not form a colloid mixture.

I see. Then, are gelling agents solvents or colloids?

Gelling agents can be both solvent or colloids. They are solvent for substances that can be dissolved like $\ce{NaCl}$. They produce colloids with substances that are not dissolved but suspended. The optical effect is different. A solution is transparent. A colloidal suspension is not transparent. The light is diffused in all directions when crossing a colloidal suspension.

I think I phrased my questions badly. I meant: are gels(made from water and gelling agents) solution or colloids?

@new, They are colloids.
